# Заполнить структуру при создании

Tags: c++, c++11, структуры, инициализация

Есть структура:

```
 struct ClearNode {
        lu a;
        BYTE hasChild;
        BYTE c;
    };
```

И есть ее создание:

```
    ClearNode outputData;
    outputData.a = rootTree->a;
    outputData.c = rootTree->c;
```

Можно ли сделать что-то типа:

```
ClearNode outputData(a: rootTree->a, c: rootTree->c);
```

Т.е. заполнить структуру при создании?

Если да - то как?

Comment: @SKIP т.к. эта структура пишется в файл - то не знаю, можно ли добавлять его (не увеличится ли вес)

Comment: `struct Test{int i; std::string j;};` main: `Test test = {10, "test"};`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516657/c-structure-initialization , https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: @SKIP Понял, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, вы можете просто использовать инициализацию -

```
struct ClearNode {
    unsigned long a;
    unsigned char hasChild;
    unsigned char c;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ClearNode cl{7,2,1};
}
```

Можно написать (если нужно) конструктор. На размер структуры это никак не повлияет - [смотрите сами](https://ideone.com/idy420)...

Comment: Огромное спасибо